# jquery scrollTop works but doesn't move the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a DIV loaded via $.load() function.
On complete, I execute $('#my_div').scrollTop(0);

It works, the content is visible from first line, but, and this is the problem, the left scrollbar, added from browser to allow user to scroll div content, is not moved, it stay where was before .scrollTop().

So if my user manually scroll down to bottom, then ask for data refresh, the data will be refreshed, and the content will be visible from first line, but scrollbar remain at bottom, so if the user clicks, the content will be scrolled down to bottom !

Is there a way to force browser to redraw the div or something to do to have even the scrollbar scrolled to top ?

EDIT 1: I tried to remove the div itself from the dom, add a 'loading' text, then recreate again after load is complete, but nothing changes...

EDIT 2: i'm NOT scrolling at the top of the page, it's a modal (i'm using twitter bootstrap)

EDIT 3: this is my modal

```
<!-- Modal di verifica duplicati -->
<div id="fullDataModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="fullDataModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <i class="icon-spinner icon-spin"></i> 
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><?php echo Yii::t('General','close'); ?></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is javascript code

```
        $("DIV#fullDataModal DIV.modal-body")
            .load ("'. $this->createUrl("view", array("ajax" => true, "id" => $model->id))  .'"+contact_id, function(){
                $("DIV.modal-body").scrollTop( 0 );
            });
```

Please note: accidentally this works !

```
$("DIV.modal-body").scrollTop( 1 );
```

Why ?

Comment: if it works then you should answer yourself and close the question

Comment: Uhm... it's not working .. it works using a trick, so it is not working..

Comment: but it works for you at least :) and that's what you need

Comment: I had the same issue and this worked: $("DIV.modal-body").scrollTop( 1 );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).scrollTop($('#my_div').offset().top);
```

Comment: if you are scrolling to the top of the page why not use window.location.href = '#' ?

Comment: Sorry, really, it's works, but the sroll itself is not 'precise'. It scroll to the 'half' of the title, so, it's not the 'top', but 'near the top'...

Comment: I edit the question: i'm not scrolling the page, i'm scrolling in a modal created using twitter bootstrap

Comment: yes this code scrolls to the element not the top of the page ,, if you want the top use $(document).scrollTop()

Comment: if your case is different please add your code to the question

Comment: I added my html and my javascript, please not that i found an 'accidentally working' workaround

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31855/discussion-between-cme64-and-realtebo)

Comment: something seems wrong with loading ,, could you join the chat discussion ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out why `$("DIV.modal-body").scrollTop(0);` didn't redraw the scroll bar but `$("DIV.modal-body").scrollTop(1);` does? I'm seeing the same behavior when dealing with a UL I'm hiding and showing when I'm repopulating it. `.scrollTop(1);` works for me too, but I'm also curious as to why.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the scrollTop(1) workaround, the following works:

```
$("#mydiv").scrollTop(1).scrollTop(0)
```