# jQuery function scrollTop doesn't work correctly when using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrolltop

I have a situation where I am loading content into a overlay window and sometimes it will have a scroll applied with `overflow-y: auto;` and if users scroll and then click the button again I would like the scroll to go back to the top, not where they last left it.

This works fine *without* using Bootstrap, but once you start using bootstrap methods to show/hide a overlay window it doesn't work.

Specifically this is what doesn't work:

```
$('#preview .main').scrollTop(0);
```

However, for whatever reason this *does* work:

```
$('#preview .main').scrollTop(1);
```

I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180621/jquery-scroll-to-top-of-bootstrap-modal) but I am not using bootstrap *modals*, so it doesn't really apply to me; I also read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143497/jquery-scrolltop-works-but-doesnt-move-the-scrollbar) but the accepted answer didn't work for me.

Sample code:

**HTML**

```
<section class="row collapse" id="preview">
      <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="side col-xs-2">

            </div>
            <div class="main col-xs-4">
                  <div class="content_wrapper">
                        <div class="loader">
          loading...
                        </div>
                        <div class="content post">

                        </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</section>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#preview">

<input type="button" id="hide" value="Hide Content" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#preview">
```

**CSS**

```
#preview {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#preview .wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 !important;
    border-left: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
    border-right: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F2F2F2; 
}

#preview .side {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px 30px 15px 30px;   
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

#preview .main {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    padding: 10px 13px 16px 13px;   
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#preview .main .content_wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 32px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

#preview .main .content_wrapper .loader {
    text-align: center;
}

#preview .main .content_wrapper .loader p {
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#preview .main .content_wrapper .content {
    display: none;
}

#btn {
  margin-top: 210px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    var content_el = $('#preview .main .content_wrapper .content'); 
    var loader_el = $('#preview .loader');

    content_el.hide();
    loader_el.show();

    // Set the content
    content_el.html('some content here...');

    loader_el.hide();

    // Show the content area
    content_el.show();

    // Reset the scroll position of preview window
    $('#preview .main').scrollTop(0);  

});
```

**CodePen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVzppz

Having to set it to 1 and not 0 isn't a big deal, so I guess just wondering why it works on `1` and not `0`?

Comment: You want to hide the preview DIV and scroll it to Top as well? That too on click of both buttons. Little confusing though.

Comment: @LokeshYadav Yes, whilst this setup on CodePen isn't identical to the real setup, it has the exact same functionality. I am just using the buttons here to help demonstrate it better.